# Can't save entries with dynamic subfolder path in Matrix

Tags: matrix, error-message, subfolder

I have a Matrix field which contains several assets fields. Each has the dynamic subfolder path set to `{owner.section.handle}`, so I can reuse the Matrix in multiple sections, but keep the assets organized.

When I try to save an entry with an image, i get the error:

> Craft\InvalidSubpathException
>
> Could not resolve the subpath “{owner.section.handle}”

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out -- I'll leave the question up in case anyone else runs into the issue.

I had Assets fields in my Matrix, but I also had a SuperTable field in the Matrix which contained an image. That was the one causing the error. Changing the subfolder path to `{owner.owner.section.handle}` solved the problem.